# Using pushState to remove forward button - without adding to history?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, browser-history

I am trying to remove the forward button. The issue is that if I use pushState, it adds to the history.

So if I'm go from state1 to state2, and then to state3, if I try to hide the forward button when going back to state2, it requires 2 clicks to go back to state1 after.

replaceState doesn't seem to hide the forward button.

Is there a workaround for this?

PS - I am using ui-router 1.x but don't think that has to do with the issue.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include your attempts, add a code sample that reproduces the issue and explain what's wrong with it.

Comment: Yes please edit your post before Madara comes and cast Infinite Tsukuyomi on your post

Comment: Great now I need to watch Naruto. (I'll edit in a bit)